# Intel XDK Build iOS

Tags: intel

I am building my first iOS app with Intel XDK. I am ready to deploy it to the App Store. My submission on the Apple store is stating that "your binary indicates support for 3gs". Actually, I don't want to support 3gs. How do I modify my Intel XDK project so that it does not support / build for the iPhone 3GS?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build settings tab and specify what your targeted OS version.